# Does is_numeric() mean a var is safe for MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Question says it all hopefully, if I check a variable returns true for is_numeric(), is it ok to put directly into the MySQL query, or do I need to apply standard escaping? I'm thinking null character, overflow exploits and stuff.

An ambiguous example would be:

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['user_id'])) {
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = ".$_GET['user_id']);
}
```

The datatype in MySQL is INT().

Comment: is it $_GET['user_id'] or $_POST['user_id']?

Comment: Was just the example :) Changed them both to $_GET

Comment: **Never mix data validation with data sanitization!** if(is_numeric( is data validation. **It can be changed in the future**. While sanitization rules would remain the same. The only benefit of prepared statements lays on the same ground: it doesn't *think* if you need to sanitize a variable, or not. **It does it.** Period. So, be smart and learn from this good practice. validate your input as you wish, but sanitize database variables unconditionally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The safest way in my opinion is to convert the user_id to an integer, if it's invalid it will return 0.

```
$user_id = (int) $_GET['user_id'];

if ($user_id > 0) {
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = " . $user_id);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Considering that "10e3" `is_numeric`, no.

If you want numbers (as in, *only digits*), you'll have to check for [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) (which would still break SQL for numbers like `0123`) or cast the number to an `int` or `float`. If it's acceptable for the number to be something other than *all digits*, you'll need to apply the SQL safe escaping and quoting.

Comment: Thanks, would it be a good idea to just replace my use of `is_numeric()` with `ctype_digit()` in the example? I am only checking basic numeric ids so it would just be a whole number. The type casting method below also appeals to me.

Answer (score 4):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php:

> Be careful when using is_numeric() to escape SQL strings.  is_numeric('0123') returns true but 0123 without quotes cannot be inserted into SQL.  PHP interprets 0123 without quotes as a literal octal number; but SQL just throws a syntax error.

Comment: I found that MySQL does not return a syntax error, but PHP reads it as an octal number so passes a completely different number to MySQL. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

Because the programm must be ready for variant for no-existing `id` this single row should be enough:

```
mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = %d LIMIT 1",$_GET['user_id']));
```

Whatever what will not be a decimal number we pass inside the `sprintf` will be turned to decimal. The zero (~ bad input) has the same state as no existing id.

Saving condition and declaring extra variable.